# Объявление объектов с круглыми скобками

Tags: c++, объявление

`struct S {};`

В чём разница между

```
S s;
S* s_ptr = new S;
```

и

```
S s();
S* s_ptr = new S();
```

?

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Comment: Простой ответ:  1. создание обьекта в стеке и в куче.    2.   Прототип функции и  создание обьекта в куче с объязательной инициализацией(если нет конструктора, то инициализация значением по умолчанию.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Про new

Для типов, имеющих недефаултный конструктор разницы нет. А вот для встроенных типов и типов с дефаултным конструктором вариант со скобками будет инициализироваться нулём, а без скобок - оставаться с мусором внутри.

http://codepad.org/vYwvxMn5

```
#include <cstdio>

struct smth
{
  int value;
  smth() : value(0) { puts("Constructor called"); }
};

struct defctr
{
  int value;
};

#define CHECK(TYPE, ARGS, VALUE) do                              \
  {                                                              \
    TYPE *x = new TYPE ARGS;                                     \
    printf("%p %08X new %s%s\n", (void*)x, VALUE, #TYPE, #ARGS); \
    delete x;                                                    \
  } while(0)

int main()
{
  CHECK(int, (-1), *x);
  CHECK(int,     , *x);
  CHECK(int, ()  , *x);

  CHECK(defctr,   , x->value);
  CHECK(defctr, (), x->value);

  CHECK(smth,   , x->value);
  CHECK(smth, (), x->value);

  return 0;
}
```

```
0x8110438 FFFFFFFF new int(-1)
0x8110438 93939393 new int
0x8110438 00000000 new int()
0x8110438 93939393 new defctr
0x8110438 00000000 new defctr()
Constructor called
0x8110438 00000000 new smth
Constructor called
0x8110438 00000000 new smth()
```

## Без new

Это - переменная:

```
S s;
```

А это - прототип функции:

```
S s();
```

Comment: Для классовых типов тоже есть разница. Члены тоже останутся не инициализированными, если конструктор об этом не позаботился. Можете удалить в smth конструктор и посмотреть разницу.

Comment: *"Для объектов разницы нет."* Разница есть, если у класса автоматически сгенерированный конструктор по умолчанию, либо если этот конструктор отмечен как `=default` в теле класса.

Comment: @Croessmah, исправил. Если можешь улучшить формулировку, буду только рад.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, исправил. Если можешь улучшить формулировку, буду только рад.

Comment: @Croessmah, если конструктор не инициализировал что-то, то там мусор в обоих случаях: http://codepad.org/rhu0pf3R (смотреть на `ectr`).

Comment: @Qwertiy все правильно. Я чуть намудрил с формулировкой. Отличие new от new() в применяемом типе инициализации. new без инициализатора применяется инициализация по-умолчанию. new с инициализатором - прямая инициализация. При прямой инициализации с пустыми скобками будет произведена инициализация значением. А далее нужно осмотреть на инициализацию членов класса для каждого вида инициализации. Для инициализации по-умолчанию, ко всем членам применяется инициализация по-умолчанию. Для простых типов это приводит впоследствии к недетерминированным значениям.

Comment: @Qwertiy если же у нас инициализация значением, то, в случае если нет объявленного пользователем конструктора, к членам применяется инициализация значением, которая для целочисленных типов выльется в инициализацию нулем. Если же у этого класса есть объявленный пользователем конструктор, то к не инициализированным явно (каким либо способом) членам применяется инициализация по-умолчанию. Это конечно же, далеко не все правила и те что описал тоже не полные (например, не описал = default или =delete).

Answer (score 3):

Во-первых, `S s();` - это объявление функции, а не объекта (см. [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)).
Чтобы он считался объектом, можно сделать либо `S s = S();`, либо `S s{};`, смысл тот же.

Во-вторых, кроме `()` можно использовать еще `{}`, они ведут себя одинаково. Единственная разница - `{}` не подвержен most vexing parse.

В-третих, `new` не меняет смысла скобочек (но убирает возможный most vexing parse).

---

Если `S` - числовой тип, `enum`, указатель или указатель-на-член, то добавление `()` (или `{}`) инициализирует его нулем. Иначе он остается неинициализированным.

Если `S` - класс, для которого вы сами написали конструктор по умолчанию, то добавление `()` (или `{}`) ничего не меняет.

Если `S` - класс, для которого компилятор сгенерировал констурктор по умолчанию (т.е. либо вы вообще не описывали для него конструкторы, либо отметили конструктор по умолчанию как `=default` в теле класса: `S() = default;`), то добавление `()` (или `{}`) инициализирует нулями все поля, которые иначе остались бы неинициализированными (т.е. те поля, для которых не указан инициализатор по умолчанию).

Написанное выше не распространяется на глобальные/статические объекты - они (и их поля) никогда не остаются неинициализированными. Если их (или какие-то из их полей) не инициализровать, то они зануляются.

Примеры:

```
void foo()
{
    int x; // Не инициализирован.
    int x{}; // 0
    void *x; // Не инициализирован.
    void *x{}; // nullptr

    struct A
    {
        int f;
        int g = 1;

        // Не влияет на результат:
        // A() = default;
    };
    A a; // f не инициализирован, g = 1
    A a{}; // f = 0, g = 1

    struct B
    {
        int f;
        int g = 1;
        int h;

        B() : h(2) {}
    };
    B b;   // f не инициализирован, g = 1, h = 2.
    B b{}; // f не инициализирован, g = 1, h = 2.
}
```

Comment: `int x; // Не инициализирован.` если это статическая переменная, то будет произведена инициализация нулем. Инициализация не будет произведена, если это автоматическая переменная. В данном случае нет никакого основания полагать, что переменная автоматическая. Объявите эти переменные в функции, т.к. на уровне файла они будут статическими.

Comment: @Croessmah Поправил.